# Could someone help me with a weird firebase error while posting images?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to upload a post on firebase which contains: one thumbnail image, and unlimited subposts (like the content of the thumbnail). I have 3 steps on posting the pictures.

**1:** handle the upload image task.

**2:** create a "bulkUpload" function that creates image paths for each subpost.

**3:** call the "bulkUpload" (which also calls the upload image task)

*The structure looks something like this:*

```
(postid) {
    author: (author)
    likes: (number)
    pathToImage: (path)
    postId: (id)
    subposts {
        (id): (path)
        (id): (path)
        ...etc
    }
    userId: (userid)
}
```

Simple and gets it working. But, not really. There is a strange problem that occurs with the subposts.
When I post the post, everything works, except for the subposts. The subposts, when posting the set of images for the first time, don't show.
Without adding or removing subposts, I tried posting for the second time, this time, the subposts do show. But double the amount I selected in the picker and what shows in the `imageViews`.

I will link the code from **pastebin** since its a little lengthy (and stackoverflow doesn't like a lot of code).
But hope I can get this working.

https://pastebin.com/rpLZT6nm

Comment: Your whole approach is wrong. You do not access anything in a collection view cell directly from outside. You modify the collection view's data model (e.g. add a reference to the image to it) and reload the collection view, so that `cellForItemAt` will run and set the image internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Matt is right, in your case you should update your data model, which is presented by the collectionView and call [reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata) or [reloadItems(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618055-reloaditems)

```
    self.updateModel();
    self.collectioView.reloadData()
    self.collectioView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)]);
```

But if you need direct acces to [visible cells](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618020-indexpathsforvisibleitems), you can use other workflow:

```
    let image : UIImage? = nil
    let path = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    let visiblePaths = self.collectioView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    if visiblePaths.contains(path) {
        if let cell = self.collectioView.cellForItem(at: path) as? UploadSubPostCell {
            cell.previewStep.image = image;
        }
    }
```

You can use such workflow to update only visible cells, because invisible cells will be reused before show to the screen

Comment: Almost!!! Its just not recognizing a cellForIte in the UploadSubPostCell. (the same with indexPathsForVisibleItems...)